# Return null dropdown item in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a dropdown widget working fine but I'd need to hide the current element I'm displaying the dropdown for.

```
items: Provider.of<MyInvestments>(context)
                        .list
                        .map((portfolio) {
                      // if (currentPorfolio["documentID"] ==
                      //     portfolio["documentID"]) {
                      //   return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      //     value: null,
                      //     child: Container(),
                      //   );
                      // } else {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: portfolio["title"],
                        child: Text(portfolio["title"]),
                      );
                      //}
                    }).toList(),
```

The commented part is what doesn't work. Well, it works, but it returns the empty container. I tried returning directly null or just nothing but that gives me an error.

Comment: you cant pass null value to dropdown menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove your current portfolio from list before map method.

```
items: Provider.of<MyInvestments>(context)
                        .list.where((portfolio) => 
                             currentPorfolio["documentID"] != portfolio["documentID"])
                             .map((portfolio) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: portfolio["title"],
                        child: Text(portfolio["title"]),
                      );
                      //}
                    }).toList(),
```